# How can I perform linear and trend extrapolation on panel data?

Tags: r, na, missing-data, extrapolation

I am trying to extrapolate the following missing values (NAs) in my data with this line of code but it is not working.

My Data:

```
 landkreis  jahr     deDomains 
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Ahrweile…  2007  NA                   
 2 Ahrweile…  2008  NA                
 3 Ahrweile…  2009  NA               
 4 Ahrweile…  2010  NA                  
 5 Ahrweile…  2011  NA                              
 6 Ahrweile…  2012  NA                              
 7 Ahrweile…  2013  22224                               
 8 Ahrweile…  2014  22460                               
 9 Ahrweile…  2015  2379                               
10 Ahrweile…  2016  22769                               
11 Ahrweile…  2017  23268                               
12 Aichach-…  2007  NA                              
13 Aichach-…  2008  NA                              
14 Aichach-…  2009  NA                              
15 Aichach-…  2010  NA                              
16 Aichach-…  2011  NA                              
17 Aichach-…  2012  NA                              
18 Aichach-…  2013  21341                               
19 Aichach-…  2014  21393                               
20 Aichach-…  2015  21338
```

I am trying to extapolate the NAs on the deDomains variable with the following code but it doesn't work

```
 df_complete <- df_complete %>% 
          group_by(landkreis) %>%
        mutate(`deDomains` = approxExtrap(which(!is.na(`deDomains`)),
`deDomains`[!is.na(`deDomains`)])$y)
```

I am using the `approxExtrap()` command from the `Hmisc` package for linear extrapolation.

Comment: please post the result of `dput(df_complete)` inside your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify your `xout`. The `NA`s are actually handled by the function. You may want to look into the `approx` function where you can find some examples (for *inter*polation though, but it's similar); type `?approx`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(Hmisc)
df_complete %>% 
  group_by(landkreis) %>%
  mutate(`deDomains`=approxExtrap(x=jahr, y=deDomains, xout=jahr)$y)
# # A tibble: 20 x 3
# # Groups:   landkreis [2]
#    landkreis  jahr deDomains
#    <fct>     <int>     <dbl>
#  1 Ahrweile…  2007     22224
#  2 Ahrweile…  2008     22224
#  3 Ahrweile…  2009     22224
#  4 Ahrweile…  2010     22224
#  5 Ahrweile…  2011     22224
#  6 Ahrweile…  2012     22224
#  7 Ahrweile…  2013     22224
#  8 Ahrweile…  2014     22460
#  9 Ahrweile…  2015      2379
# 10 Ahrweile…  2016     22769
# 11 Ahrweile…  2017     23268
# 12 Aichach-…  2007     21341
# 13 Aichach-…  2008     21341
# 14 Aichach-…  2009     21341
# 15 Aichach-…  2010     21341
# 16 Aichach-…  2011     21341
# 17 Aichach-…  2012     21341
# 18 Aichach-…  2013     21341
# 19 Aichach-…  2014     21393
# 20 Aichach-…  2015     21338
```

Or using `by`:

```
library(Hmisc)
do.call(rbind, by(df_complete, df_complete$landkreis, function(x) {
  transform(x, 
            deDomains=approxExtrap(x=x$jahr, y=x$deDomains, xout=x$jahr)$y
            )
  }))
#              landkreis jahr deDomains
# Ahrweile….1  Ahrweile… 2007     22224
# Ahrweile….2  Ahrweile… 2008     22224
# Ahrweile….3  Ahrweile… 2009     22224
# Ahrweile….4  Ahrweile… 2010     22224
# Ahrweile….5  Ahrweile… 2011     22224
# Ahrweile….6  Ahrweile… 2012     22224
# Ahrweile….7  Ahrweile… 2013     22224
# Ahrweile….8  Ahrweile… 2014     22460
# Ahrweile….9  Ahrweile… 2015      2379
# Ahrweile….10 Ahrweile… 2016     22769
# Ahrweile….11 Ahrweile… 2017     23268
# Aichach-….12 Aichach-… 2007     21341
# Aichach-….13 Aichach-… 2008     21341
# Aichach-….14 Aichach-… 2009     21341
# Aichach-….15 Aichach-… 2010     21341
# Aichach-….16 Aichach-… 2011     21341
# Aichach-….17 Aichach-… 2012     21341
# Aichach-….18 Aichach-… 2013     21341
# Aichach-….19 Aichach-… 2014     21393
# Aichach-….20 Aichach-… 2015     21338
```

***Edit:*** To extrapolate using a "trend" you may use e.g. `na_kalman` from the `imputeTS` package.

```
library(imputeTS)
res <- do.call(rbind, by(df_complete, df_complete$landkreis, function(x) {
  transform(x, 
            deDomains.ex=na_kalman(x$deDomains, model = "StructTS", smooth = TRUE)
            )
  }))
#              landkreis jahr deDomains deDomains.ex
# Ahrweile….1  Ahrweile… 2007        NA     21532.16
# Ahrweile….2  Ahrweile… 2008        NA     21186.24
# Ahrweile….3  Ahrweile… 2009        NA     20840.32
# Ahrweile….4  Ahrweile… 2010        NA     20494.40
# Ahrweile….5  Ahrweile… 2011        NA     20148.48
# Ahrweile….6  Ahrweile… 2012        NA     19802.56
# Ahrweile….7  Ahrweile… 2013     22224     22224.00
# Ahrweile….8  Ahrweile… 2014     22460     22460.00
# Ahrweile….9  Ahrweile… 2015      2379      2379.00
# Ahrweile….10 Ahrweile… 2016     22769     22769.00
# Ahrweile….11 Ahrweile… 2017     23268     23268.00
# Aichach-….12 Aichach-… 2007        NA     21344.52
# Aichach-….13 Aichach-… 2008        NA     21346.28
# Aichach-….14 Aichach-… 2009        NA     21348.04
# Aichach-….15 Aichach-… 2010        NA     21349.80
# Aichach-….16 Aichach-… 2011        NA     21351.55
# Aichach-….17 Aichach-… 2012        NA     21353.31
# Aichach-….18 Aichach-… 2013     21341     21341.00
# Aichach-….19 Aichach-… 2014     21393     21393.00
# Aichach-….20 Aichach-… 2015     21338     21338.00
```

There might be better data for demonstration, but anyway let's look at a plot:

```
plot(deDomains ~ jahr, type="n", data=res)
sapply(seq(res$landkreis), function(x) 
  with(res[res$landkreis == unique(res$landkreis)[x], ], 
       {lines(jahr, deDomains.ex, col=x + 1)
         points(jahr, deDomains, col=x + 1)}))
legend("bottomleft", legend=c(as.character(unique(res$landkreis)), "true points"), 
       col=c(2, 3, 1), lty=c(1, 1, NA), pch=c(NA, NA, 1))
```

[image]

You could also look into the `imputeTS::na_seadec` function where--among kalman--other algorithms can be chosen, and also frequencies could be detected.

---

*Data:*

```
df_complete <- structure(list(landkreis = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Ahrweile…", 
"Aichach-…"), class = "factor"), jahr = c(2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2007L, 
2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L), deDomains = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22224L, 22460L, 2379L, 22769L, 23268L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21341L, 21393L, 21338L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. But the NAs are always replaced with the same value. I was looking for a solution where there is a "trend", meaning that the several NAs are not replaced by only one value. Do you know a command for that?

Comment: @LaurenzHamel Yes I do, please see edit! You could also look into the `imputeTS::na_seadec` function where--among kalman--other algorithms can be chosen, it's also able to detect frequencies.